# How can I check if a date is older then 10 days from today?

Tags: vue.js, dayjs

Im trying to see if a date is beyond different intervals, and if so add some stylesheet to them. Im using `Vuejs` version 3 for this. I have not been able to locate the issue, but the result vary. For example if `user.active.created_at` is the same date as `dayjs()`, it does return `fill-gray-400` and not `fill-green-400`. `user.active.created_at` is the last sign-in date for user.

This is my method:

```
  methods: {
    active(user){
      var isBetween = require('dayjs/plugin/isBetween')
      dayjs.extend(isBetween)
      
      if(dayjs(user.active.created_at).isBetween(dayjs().subtract(10, 'day'), dayjs(), 'day')){
        return 'fill-green-400'
      }

      if(dayjs(user.active.created_at).isBetween(dayjs().subtract(30, 'day'), dayjs(), 'day')){
        return 'fill-red-400'
      }

      return 'fill-gray-400'
      
    }
  },
```

And this is my template that im trying to add classes to

```
<div v-for="user in users">
    <icon name="chart-simple" class="flex-shrink-0 ml-2 w-3 h-3" :class="active(user)" />
</div>
```

The expected result is if a user has signed-in in the last 10 days, return `fill-green-400` and if a user has signed-in in the past 30 days, return `fill-red-400`.

Answer (score 0):

`isBetween` is excludes start and end date default.

When `user.active.created_at` is the same date as `dayjs()` your code will not enter these two if statements

try add parameter 4 `[]`

Parameter 4 is a string with two characters; '[' means inclusive, '(' exclusive

```
 if(dayjs(user.active.created_at).isBetween(dayjs().subtract(10, 'day'), dayjs(), 'day','[]')){
        return 'fill-green-400'
      }

      if(dayjs(user.active.created_at).isBetween(dayjs().subtract(30, 'day'), dayjs(), 'day', '[]')){
        return 'fill-red-400'
      }
```

reference : https://day.js.org/docs/en/plugin/is-between